# Arbitrary precision in symbolic in GNU Octave is not working

Tags: octave, gnu, arbitrary-precision

I tried to check the funny calculation of

```
x = -80538738812075974
y = 80435758145817515
z = 12602123297335631

x**3+y**3+z**3=42
```

with GNU Octave.

I used the symbolic package and wrote:

```
>> x = vpa('-80538738812075974')
x = (sym) -80538738812075974.0000000000000
>> y = vpa('80435758145817515')
y = (sym) 80435758145817515.0000000000000
>> z = vpa('12602123297335631')
z = (sym) 12602123297335631.0000000000000
>> vpa(x**3+y**3+z**3)
ans = (sym) -23634890844440363008.0000000000
```

So the answer is not 42, even with digits(50). Using wxMaxima I get the right result:

```
x : -80538738812075974;
y : 80435758145817515;
z : 12602123297335631;
x**3+y**3+z**3;
42
```

so the numbers are ok. Is it possible to work with arbitrary precision in GNU Octave?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what was wrong, but it works obviously only if all steps are done in the right order (and sym instead of vpa):

```
setenv PYTHON d:/anaconda3w64/python
pkg load symbolic
syms x y z
x = sym('-80538738812075974')
y = sym('80435758145817515')
z = sym('12602123297335631')
x**3+y**3+z**3

x = (sym) -80538738812075974
y = (sym) 80435758145817515
z = (sym) 12602123297335631
ans = (sym) 42
```

So the problem is finally solved.